# Regex and Content Grouping

Tags: google-analytics

Im setting up a Content Group with Google Analytics and we have a "/groups" page that contains about 10 sub-categories. As we change these once in a while I'd like to set up some tracking that can group all those subpages inside a Content Group. I know I can test it, but I'd like to be sure I dont miss any change. So the correct setup would be:

Page matches regex:  /groups/*

Is this correct? Or does there exist a better way to set this up?

Comment: That would probably match an arbitrary number of slashes at the end. Better try /groups/.* (the dot meaning "any character").